# Conda not recognized as a command in VSC

Tags: visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

Every time I open the terminal in Visual Studio Code, it shows an error message

> The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet...

I am using Python 3.7 and I set up its environment to use Anaconda3 (which of course I ve installed). Indeed in the bottom-left corner of VSC I see "Python 3.7.3 64-bit ('base':conda)".

When I try to run whatever I've created no error occurs, but nothing happens either.

Furthermore when I try to debug my code this is prompted to the VSC's terminal

```
cd 'c:\Users\giuli\Desktop\UDEMY COURSES\Fun apps';    
${env:PYTHONIOENCODING}='UTF-8'; 
${env:PYTHONUNBUFFERED}='1'; & 'C:\Users\giuli\Anaconda3\python.exgiuli\Anaconda3\python.exe' 'c:\Users\giuli\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.3.6558\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py' '--default' '--client' '--host' 'localhost' '--port' '56935' 'c:\Users\giuli\Desktop\UDEMY COURSES\Fun apps\bitcoin_notifications.py'
```

while the debug console remains empty.

PS: I have also installed the python extension.

Comment: How are you running your code?  Using "Run code", fn5 key, ...?

Comment: I just tried running conda from the VSCode terminal and it ran fine. Are you using conda (vitual) environments?

Comment: I ve deleted VSC and all of its folders, then I downloaded it again and now it s not showing any error about conda. Maybe I ve just solved it this way :D

Comment: Could be.  Good luck.